# Why Azure DNS Zone create afdverify subdomain automatically and how to stop?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-dns

I create a CNAME record in DNS ZONE (e.g: site1.example.com). And then, `afdverify.site1.example.com` and `site1.example.com` will be created.

I just want to create `site1.example.com` only.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58335255/6886501

Comment: I don't want to create afdverify domain, what should I do  @MarkusMeyer

Comment: Hi @kyakya, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   @Kyakya, from your query and the screenshot, I can understand that you are trying to create a CNAME record for the ‘site1.example.com’ URL. But when creating a CNAME DNS record in a DNS zone, you will have to mention its alias FQDN URL, i.e., that original URL which you are trying to mask or associate with by creating this CNAME record. Thus, I can understand from the screenshot that you are trying to create a CNANE record for the Azure front door URL in DNS zone in Azure.

As a result, when you create a CNAME record with a custom domain name for an already hosted URL, you need to ensure that the original hosted URL is reachable and available as the CNAME record created will only redirect the DNS requests to the original hosted URL only.

•   Since, in your case, you don’t want to create a subdomain regarding ‘site1.example.com’ in your DNS zone, i.e., ‘afdverify.site1.example.com’ so in that scenario, you will have to create an ‘A’ host record for the ‘site1.example.com’ in your public DNS server where your basic custom domain ‘example.com’ is registered. Once done, then create a CNAME record for the inbuilt Azure generated FQDN of that resource in your public DNS zone in that DNS server with ‘site1.example.com’ that you want.

And if you don’t want that too, then you will have to verify your custom domain in Azure, and then create resources in Azure based on the records created in DNS zone provisioned.

Comment: The answer is so long for me. But I think I know what's your meaning, and I need time to have a try.